# Scrapy: Crawl angular ng-href links?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm using selenium-webdriver to render javascript for a scrapy crawler, but it doesn't looks like the angularjs 'ng-href' links are crawled. Does scrapy crawl 'ng-href' links?  If not, how can I get it to crawl the 'ng-href' links?

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from CAP.items import Website
from scrapy.mail import MailSender

from scrapy.http import Request
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from scrapy.http import TextResponse

class HomeSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "capseleniums"
    allowed_domains = ["www.ecommerce.com", "learn.ecommerce.com", "health.ecommerce.com", "wm15.ecommerce.com", "wm13.ecommerce.com", "wm12.ecommerce.com" ]
    handle_httpstatus_list = [500, 502, 503, 504, 400, 408, 404]

    def start_requests(self):
        start_urls = reversed( [
            'http://wm12.ecommerce.com/health-wellness-center/',
            'http://wm13.ecommerce.com/Cook/',
            'http://wm15.ecommerce.com/electronics-resource-center/',
            'http://health.ecommerce.com/vitamins-wellness-center/',
            'http://learn.ecommerce.com/Tips-Ideas/',
            ] )
        return [ Request(url = start_url) for start_url in start_urls ]

    def trim(link_text):
        return link_text.strip(' \t\n\r')

    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=(),
                deny=(),
                process_value=trim,
                ),
                callback="parse_items",
                follow=False,),
    )

    def __init__(self, category=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--load-images=no'])
        super(HomeSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __del__(self):
       self.driver.stop()

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = self.driver
        hxs.get(response.url)
        time.sleep(1)
        body = hxs.page_source
        sel_response = TextResponse(url=response.url, body=body, encoding = 'utf-8')
        hxs = Selector(sel_response)
        sites = hxs.xpath('//html')
        items = []

        if response.status == 404:
            for site in sites:
                item = Website()
                item['url'] = response.meta.get('redirect_urls', [response.url])[0]
                item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
                item['status'] = response.status
                items.append(item)

            return items

        if hxs.xpath('/html/head/title/text()[contains(.,"invalid")]'):
            for site in sites:
                item = Website()
                item['url'] = response.meta.get('redirect_urls', [response.url])[0]
                item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
                item['status'] = response.status
                items.append(item)

            return items

        elif hxs.xpath('//head/link[@rel="canonical"]/@href[contains(.,"invalid-category-id")]'):
            for site in sites:
                item = Website()
                item['url'] = response.meta.get('redirect_urls', [response.url])[0]
                item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
                item['status'] = response.status
                items.append(item)

            return items

        else:
            if hxs.xpath('//*[@class="result-summary-container"]/text()[contains(.,"Showing 0 of")]'):
                for site in sites:
                    item = Website()
                    item['url'] = response.meta.get('redirect_urls', [response.url])[0]
                    item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
                    item['status'] = response.status
                    items.append(item)

                return items
```

Comment: @BeeSmears actually, it is not about the parsers used under-the-hood, it is about link extractor implementations used in scrapy, see the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I deleted my comment.  Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Why have you deleted your newest question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[By default](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.lxmlhtml.LxmlLinkExtractor), it would look for links in the `href` attribute of `a` and `area` tags.

You just need to additionally configure `attrs` argument and include `ng-href` attribute:

```
LinkExtractor(attrs=['href', 'ng-href'], callback="parse_items", follow=False),
```